# using for loop and displaying multiple results in a messagebox

Tags: c#

I am trying to see if there is a way to add multiple results I created inside a for loop and put those multiple results inside a messagebox also creating newlines per results.

I've tried this method

```
for (n = START_YEAR; n <= END_YEAR; n += INTERVAL)
    {
            a = p * (decimal)Math.Pow((1 + CONVERSION_FACTOR), n);
            MessageBox.Show("Year" + "    " + "Amount of deposit" + Environment.Newline + n + a);     
    }
```

What I've noticed was this wasn't going to display what I'm trying to get, instead it would display multiple messageboxes, but my problem is if I bring out the show messagebox line out of the for loop, I cannot display the results calculated from the for loop inside the messagebox because it cannot use the local variable from the for loop. Any hints would be grateful.

Comment: I guess you just need a List to store the calculated values and display it outside the loop once

Comment: This looks like abuse of a messagebox to me (you're not displaying a message, but what looks like it could be quite a bit of user data), you should make a new form to display this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string variable outside the loop and concatenate to it within the loop. Then after the loop, you can show the message box with all the messages.

```
string message = "";
for (n = START_YEAR; n <= END_YEAR; n += INTERVAL)
{
        a = p * (decimal)Math.Pow((1 + CONVERSION_FACTOR), n);
        message += "Year" + "    " + "Amount of deposit" + Environment.Newline + n + a + Environment.Newline ;     
}
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

As the amount of data that you are showing may be larger than possible for viewing on a MessageBox, it may be better to think about an alternative presentation method.

EDIT: Here's an alternative solution that can save you some space in your MessageBox:

```
Dictionary<int, decimal> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
for (n = START_YEAR; n <= END_YEAR; n += INTERVAL)
{
        a = p * (decimal)Math.Pow((1 + CONVERSION_FACTOR), n);
        tempDict.Add(n, a);
}
string results = "";
foreach(var pair in tempDict)
{
    results += pair.Key.ToString() + "    " + pair.Value.ToString() + Environment.Newline;
}
MessageBox.Show("Year" + "    " + "Amount of deposit" + Environment.Newline +
    results);
```

Comment: Good answers, I suggest putting result in a StringBuilder instead of string.

Comment: is there a way to make the "a" variable 0.00 decimal place? I tried tostring method on a variable and I'm getting an error

Comment: @user3828380 `pair.Value.ToString("0.00")` This really should be a separate question but I'll go ahead and answer it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your results before putting them in the message box.
Here I am using a string directly, but another good construct is a List like List.

usage might be:

```
string result = string.empty;

    for (n = START_YEAR; n <= END_YEAR; n += INTERVAL)
        {
            a = p * (decimal)Math.Pow((1 + CONVERSION_FACTOR), n);
            var temp =  "Year" + "    " + "Amount of deposit" + Environment.Newline + n + a ;
            result = result + temp;
        }

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

That said, you should probably take a look at string.Format(), which makes building strings considerably easier and more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

restraining comments regarding the quality of the code in general.
depending on the number of iterations, you may want to use a StringBuilder instead.

```
string message = "Year" + "    " + "Amount of deposit";

for (n = START_YEAR; n <= END_YEAR; n += INTERVAL)
{
    a = p * (decimal)Math.Pow((1 + CONVERSION_FACTOR), n);
    message += Environment.Newline + n + a);     
}

MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Comment: you will probably need to do some string formatting to get your numbers to align with the headers. Research String.Format()